# При сравнении одинаковых массивов консоль выдает false

Tags: javascript, массивы

```
function validSolution(board){
  let sample = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  for (i=0; i<board.length; i++) {
    let row = board[i].sort((a, b) => a-b);
      console.log(row == sample);
  }
}
       validSolution([[5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2], 
                      [6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 8],
                      [1, 9, 8, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7],
                      [8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 4, 2, 3],
                      [4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1],
                      [7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6],
                      [9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 8, 4],
                      [2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5],
                      [3, 4, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 7, 9]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в javascript == не сравнит массивы поэлементно. так тут это не работает. надо самому поэлементно проверять

Comment: большое спасибо!

Comment: @Александр, пожалуйста) вы просто попробуйте в консоли написать var a = [1,2,3]; var b=[1,2,3]; a == b  и он выдаст false. т.е.сначала проверьте на более простом примере)

Answer (score 1):

Объясню чуть по подробнее. Проблема того, что `[1, 2, 3] !== [1, 2, 3]`, в том что при сравнении объектов ( массив по сути тот же объект ) движок js сравнивает не значения, а ссылки

Когда мы создаем переменную она записывается в память. В случае с объектами в переменную возвращается не значение, а ссылка ( для оптимизации, иначе очень бы много памяти съедалось приложением ).

```
const a = [1, 2, 3]
const b = [1, 2, 3]
a === b; // false, потому что массив а и b лежат в разных местах
const c = a; // переменой с присвоится ссылка где лежит массив а
с === a; // true, так как ссылаются на один и тот же адрес в памяти
```

С примитивными типами такое не работает. Там при сравнении берется именно значение.

```
const a = 5;
const b = 5;
a === b; // true
```

*Возможно, объяснение этому в том, что `a` и `b` (в случае примитивных типов данных) тоже содержат ссылку на адрес в памяти, где хранится значение 5. Суть в том, что значение 5 константно и не может быть изменено, поэтому и ссылка константа ( но это не точно )*

Answer (score 0):

вы можете использовать метод lodash [difference](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#difference) для сравнения массивов.

```js
  if(!_.difference([2, 1], [2, 3]).length) {
     console.log('1. arrays are equal');
  } else { 
     console.log('1. arrays are not equal');
  };
  
  
  if(!_.difference([2, 1], [2, 1]).length) {
     console.log('2. arrays are equal');
  } else { 
     console.log('2. arrays are not equal');
  };
  
  
    
  if(!_.difference([1, 2], [2, 1]).length) {
     console.log('3. arrays are equal');
  } else { 
     console.log('3. arrays are not equal');
  };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

С использованием данного метода порядок элементов в массиве не имеет значения.